# can't connect to main routers

Tags: networking, router, media

plz help me ... i can't connect to the main router through fiber media converter .. but it works perfectly
in the daytime ....... starting at around 6 pm to next morning 9 am it works randomly .. i can't get stable internet during that time..mostly .. my home routers said " wan port plugged " but i can ping the main routers from my ph thorough mobile data
(so main router isn't at fault ). i also changed mac address on my home router. but it still doesn't work...also i connect directly from media converter to my pc ..it still doesn't work ...
here is some photo...
https://plus.google.com/photos/103955282699327498949/al...

Comment: Multiple dots are bad style. Just use a single dot to end a sentence. Take some time to format this probably and consider reading [how to ask a good question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask). Your image link isn't working for me. StackExchange also has its own upload feature (based on imgur). You could just use that if I'm not mistaken (the little picture icon while composing a question).